# Windows azure table storage indexOutOfRange exception on entity read

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I have this little code to read all the entries form the a table storage. Here is my simple model:

```
public class LineEntity : TableServiceEntity
{
    public XElement Data { get; set; }

    public LineEntity(string rowKey)
    {
        PartitionKey = "Line";
        RowKey = rowKey;
    }

    public LineEntity()
    {
    }
}
```

And here is the code to read it:

```
var StorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(RoleEnvironment.GetConfigurationSettingValue("StorageConnectionString"));
var TableClient = StorageAccount.CreateCloudTableClient();
var ServiceContext = TableClient.GetDataServiceContext();
var models = ServiceContext.CreateQuery<LineEntity>("lines").ToList();
```

For some reason the last line will throw the following exception in cloud:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>OutOfRangeInput</Code><Message>One of the request inputs is out of range.
RequestId:8a16121a-237c-4015-99cb-b1bbdb7ab7a7
Time:2012-04-30T07:39:42.6396851Z</Message></Error>
```

It works perfectly fine in development. Any clues on this one?

Thanks,

Comment: Check the value of the rowkey does not contain any restricted characters:  [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd179338(v=MSDN.10).aspx)

Comment: @RichBower I have absolutely no data in that tabel, I expect it to return a empty list

Comment: Did you forget to create the table?

Comment: @smarx created it deleted it and created again, named it with lower cases or upper cases, no luck :(

Comment: What happens when you comment out the XElement property on your TableServiceEntity?  Also, assuming here that your query is also context.CreateQuery<LineEntity>(..) and not CreateQuery<Line>(...) like you have.

Comment: @dunnry, I think the error is coming from the server (on a query), so I wouldn't expect the shape of the class to matter.

Comment: @Calin, is it possible the storage account doesn't exist? (Or maybe you tried to use a capital letter or other invalid characters in the account name?)

Comment: @smarx - True.  Easiest is probably to open up Fiddler, turn off SSL on connection and just watch the request.  Make sure you don't have some other startup code that is trying a CreateIfNotExist type of PUT that causes that error.

Answer (score 1):

Should not this line

```
var models = ServiceContext.CreateQuery<Line>("lines").ToList();
```

instead be

```
var models = ServiceContext.CreateQuery<LineEntity>("lines").ToList();
```

Comment: Yes it should, thanks I've update the post, I've extracted the code from a base class and changed names around a littel